# How can I return the color at a coordinate in an image?

Tags: image-processing, image

I have an imported and cropped image:

```
TestPicture = Import["filepath.jpg"];
TestPictureCropped = ImageCrop[TestPicture, Min[ImageDimensions[TestPicture]]];
```

How can I specify a coordinate in the image and return the color of the nearest pixel to the coordinate?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example:

```
tp = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Airplane"}];
Manipulate[Column@{tp, Extract[ImageData[tp], Round /@ p]}, 
          {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: ImageValue is also another choice

Comment: This answer is incorrect because it messes up different coordinate systems, as can be seen with `tp = Image@IdentityMatrix[100]`. `PixelValue` and `ImageValue` are the preferred way to accomplish this task.

Comment: This gives the wrong values! The values in `p` are coordinates, so they are 0-based, start at the bottom-left corner and are stored in x/y order. `Extract` expects array indices, which are 1-based, start at the top-left corner and are in row/column (i.e. y/x) order. So the values you get are transposed, upside down and shifted by one pixel.

Comment: Way to go beli :D

Answer (score 12):

```
tp = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
Manipulate[Column @ {tp, ImageValue[tp, p]}, {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image: a Manipulate for picking colors]

Answer (score 11):

As a side-note - you can quickly get color info from images using image assistant. Just click once on the image and in version 9 assistant will appear below:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Also worth noting is that there's a companion function to `ImageValue`, called `PixelValue`. The difference between the two is, as far as I can tell from the documentation, that `ImageValue` interpolates the color of a coordinate according to the colors of nearby pixels, whereas `PixelValue` finds the color of the pixel whose centre is nearest to the integer values of the coordinates. The difference is hard to spot on smooth photographs, but possible:

```
tp = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
Manipulate[Column
  [{tp,
   Text[p],
   Text["ImageValue"],
   ImageValue[tp, p],
   Graphics[{
     RGBColor[ImageValue[tp, p]],
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 1}]}],
   Text["PixelValue"],
   PixelValue[tp, p],
   Graphics[{
     RGBColor[PixelValue[tp, p]],
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 1}]}]
   }],
 {{p, {1, 1}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image: pixelvalue]

(Code adapted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24841/61))

Comment: As you hinted, in addition to `ImageValue` interpolating neighboring pixel values, the coordinate systems of `ImageValue` an `PixelValue` are off by one half. See the 'Properties and Relations' section of http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PixelValue.html